# How do I set a value so that I can access in every methods?

Tags: java

Based on the title, how do I set a value passed from a method and set it so that I can access it globally?

For example

A.java

```
// A.java

public class A
{
    new B(2);
}
```

In B.java

```
// B.java

public class B
{
    B(int num)
    {
        // Stuffs to do
    }
}
```

From the example, I pass the value(2) from A.java to B.java. But in B.java, how do I make the value globally so that I can access in every methods.

Comment: Instance fields. Don't try to make things global for no reason. Make then scoped to an object and re-use the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class B
{
    int classWideInt;

    B(int num)
    {
        classWideInt = num;
        // Stuffs to do
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the value of a variable using the same instance of class B then add an instance member variable. If you want the value to be set and shared by all the instances then add a public static variable in B.java and set its value using constructor input.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class B
{
    private int number;

    public int getNumber()
    {
        return number;
    }

    public B(int num)
    {
       this.number = num;
    }
}
```

Once B(int num) is called, you can access number value via it's getter method like this.

```
B bObj = new B(10);
bObj.getNumber(); // will return value of 10
```

Comment: `B bObj = new bObj(10);` correct? Or is it suppose to be `B bObj = new B(10);`?

Comment: @user273371 Thanks for pointing it out. That was a typo from side. Modified post.